# How can I restore Mac OS X after installing Windows 7 without Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-7, macos

I installed Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro without using Boot Camp. Now only Windows 7 boots; the Mac partition is fine but does not boot.

How can I restore Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

The function key is the key which gives you the boot options, i.e., OS X/Windows 7/HD recovery.

Remember to boot to OS X first to eject the Windows 7 disk.  I used a boot disk which worked great.  If like for me the CD option to write Windows data to did not work, try using a flash card but remember to unmount the flash card whilst in OS X mode.

Answer (score 0):

When the Mac starts and you hear the chime, hold and keep the Alt key pressed. This should give you a selection of bootable partitions.  Select the MacOS partition with the arrow keys and press enter.

Once you are running OS X, go to System Configuration -> Startup-Disk and select it as the startup drive.

Answer (score -1):

Try starting up with the <kbd>X</kbd> key held down - this should cause your Mac to start up from the first Mac OS X partition it finds. Alternatively, hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> while starting up, and you should be presented with a list of startup disks to choose from - select the Mac OS X partition with the arrow keys.

If neither of these work, insert the Mac OS X restore DVD that came with your Mac, and start up from it by holding down the <kbd>C</kbd> key on startup. Then, use Disk Utility from the Utilities menu to verify and/or repair your hard disk, and use Startup Disk, also from the Utilities menu, to select your Mac partition as your startup disk.

A caveat, though: without Boot Camp, I'm not entirely sure how easily you will be able to boot back into Windows once you've got into Mac OS X (I presume you will know more about this than me since you did it at least once). Consider using Boot Camp or an alternative like [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) if you intend to switch between Mac OS X and Windows frequently.